# Trying to read matrix in Java

Tags: java

Hi guys im trying to read from input a number that determines the size of matrix to be created. Then read said matrix and reproduce it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int dim = in.nextInt();
    char[][] tab = new char[dim][dim];
    in.nextLine();
    String temp = in.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < dim - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim - 1; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = temp.charAt(j);
        }
        temp = in.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            System.out.print(tab[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Thing is it is ignoring the last char of eache line and the last line. Testing with this input:

```
4
XXXX
OOO.
....
....
```

Comment: `i < dim - 1` should be `i < dim`. Same for the condition in the inner loop.

Comment: Just take the red pill :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first double for-loop (the one that reads the input into your tab-matrix) should say `i < dim` instead of `i < dim - 1`, and idem for `j`in the inner for-loop

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim ; i++) { //Removed - 1
    for (int j = 0; j < dim ; j++) { //Removed - 1
        tab[i][j] = temp.charAt(j);
    }
    temp = in.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bounds on the loops when creating your matrix are incorrect. You should either do

```
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dim - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= dim - 1; j++) {
```

But don't mix the two. Pick either strictly less than a bound or less than or equal to the bound - 1.

Answer (score 0):

you just had a small issue you had to go to the last dimension so for an array of 5 you should go til 4 but in the code it goes just to 3 because of the `int i = 0; **i < dim - 1**; i++`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int dim = in.nextInt();
    char[][] tab = new char[dim][dim];
    in.nextLine();
    String temp = in.nextLine();

    for (int i = 0; i <= dim - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim - 1; j++) {
            tab[i][j] = temp.charAt(j);
        }
        temp = in.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dim; j++) {
            System.out.print(tab[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```